# Append elements to element every x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a various number of `<td>` tags with various contents with the following code:

```
for (var i = 0 - dOW; i < dIM; i++) {
    var day = i + 1;
    if (day > 0) {
        if (day === d) {
            $("#calendar").append("<td>[" + day + "]</td>");
        } else {
            $("#calendar").append("<td>" + day + "</td>");
        }
    } else {
        $("#calendar").append("<td>s</td>");
    }
}
```

Which results with:

> s s   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  [16]    17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31

Is there a way to wrap every 7 elements in a `<tr>` tag, so that the HTML would be:

```
<tr>
  <td>s</td>
  <td>s</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
...
```

Full code:

```
function calendar(d){   
    var t = new Date(d);                        // Today [Wed Jan 16 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)]
    var d = t.getDate();                        // Today's date (1-31) [16]
    var y = t.getFullYear();                    // Full year [2013]
    var m = t.getMonth();                       // Month (0-11) [0]
    var mN = [                                  // Month name array (0-11)
                "January", 
                "February", 
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
              ];
    var fM = mN[m];                             // Full month name [January]
    var dIM = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate();  // Number of days in current month (1-31) [31]
    var dOW = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay();       // Day of the first day of the month (0-6) [2]
    var nOW = Math.ceil((dIM + dOW) / 7);       // Number of weeks in the month, including space [5]


            for (var i = 0 - dOW; i < dIM; i++){
                var day = i + 1;
                if (day > 0){
                    if (day === d){
                        $("#calendar").append("<td>[" + day + "]</td>");
                    } else {
                        $("#calendar").append("<td>" + day + "</td>");
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#calendar").append("<td>s</td>");
                }
            }

    }


// "1 March 2013"
calendar(new Date());
```

So far I've tried separating it into two `for` loops, one set up for the number of rows, the other set up for the columns, but that didn't allow me to use the `if` statement that allowed me to put in the spacer div:

```
 if (day === d) {
        $("#calendar").append("<td>[" + day + "]</td>");
    } else {
        $("#calendar").append("<td>" + day + "</td>");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating the `<tr>`s after creating all the `<td>`s, may I suggest doing both at the same time?

```
var count = 0, $row;

for (var i = 0 - dOW; i < dIM; i++) {
    var day = i + 1;
    if (count % 7 === 0) {
        $row = $('<tr />').appendTo('#calendar');
    }
    if (day > 0) {
        if (day === d) {
            $row.append("<td>[" + day + "]</td>");
        } else {
            $row.append("<td>" + day + "</td>");
        }
    } else {
        $row.append("<td>s</td>");
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: That creates a new row for each element, however: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/4upXZ/

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to increment count each time. It's fixed now, I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M3n4H/

Answer (score 2):

Use nested for loops.

```
var dynamicTable= '<table cellspacing="10"';
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
  dynamicTable+= "<tr>";
  var row = i;
  row += 1;
  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
      var col = j;
      col += 1;
      dynamicTable += '<td>';
               dynamicTable += "x";// cell text
      dynamicTable += '</td>';
  }
  dynamicTable += '</tr>';
}
dynamicTable+= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a code:

```
var arr=$("#calendar").val();
var htmlCode="";
int length=arr.length;
for(var i=0;i<length/7;i++)
{
   htmlCode+="<tr>";
   for(var j=i*7;j<i*7 + 7 ; j++) 
   {
      htmlCode+="<td>"+arr[j]+"</td>";
   }
   htmlCode+="</tr>";
}
```